# Why would you ground your live terminal shunt resistor

Tags: high-voltage, shunt

I have seen some wiered things when taking the current measurement from a shunt resistor.

For instance the below circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLINWP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is the reason for "grounding" the other side of the resistor?

The entire electronics is enclosed in a tamper-proof enclosure. The PCB has the recommended clearances as well.

Comment: we need some more context - is the AC isolated from your DC? I suspect your diagram is incorrect, because if you put a shunt resistor between live and neutral you would be in for a surprise

Comment: What is your source for the other side of the resistor being grounded?

Comment: @BeB00 you are correct, it is supposed to be Load not neutral. The DC ground is connected to neutral. AC is isolated from DC. The entire electronics is enclosed in a tamper-proof enclosure. The PCB has the recommended clearances as well.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the source is the AC/DC isolated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What is the reason for "grounding" the other side of the resistor?*

The ground symbol that concerns you is **not earth** but the local 0 volt reference for your measurement circuit. For this type of circuit to work the whole of the measurement circuit needs to be powered from an isolated DC converter so that the measurement circuit can happily sit at the line voltages presented by live and neutral.

Or, put it another way, using the ground symbol on the "other side of the resistor" is to reference it to the measurement circuit and not an attempt to draw current to earth.

Comment: Thanks, Andy for answering my three posts!

Comment: How would I calculate the voltage going to the micro? So the ground symbol is 0V what will the voltage be at the other end of the resistor connected the live?

Comment: @Sandro so lets say the resistor is 10 ohm and I have 500mA flowing across. That equals a voltage of 5V. But my power supply is 3.3V, so does that I wont be able to measure 500mA or to put it another way, the maximum current I can measure across the resistor is 330mA at a source voltage of 3.3V?

Comment: @JoeyB correct. That will be the voltage difference across the resistor.

Comment: note that because this is AC, half the time there will be a negative voltage on the MCU input - depending on the shunt resistor/the current your load takes, this is probably okish, but its something to keep in mind. If that voltage goes below around -0.5V, it could break the MCU. There should be a resistor in series with the mcu input to limit the current that can flow into the mcu.

Comment: @JoeyB : it is not the 3.3V supply that will "power" the resistor, but the mains AC : so it can exceed 3.3V without difficulty if current is high enough (note that it might fry the micro if you exceed 3.3V by too much)